# How to exclude academic papers?

Tags: google-search

When I use Google to learn about technology, for example, "*locale sensitive hashing in image retrieval*", it turns up lots of academic paper results that are too complicated for me as a beginner, and I just want to learn about the introductory stuff, like blog posts on medium.com, so I want to filter out academic papers. I tried using `-paper`, which I didn't find to be effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a couple of the academic papers to look for common words on this type of content to be used for exclude those works (i.e. `-abstract`). Start looking at the headings. Usually this type of content have `abstract`, `references`, some might also have  `introduction`, `conclusion`, `keywords`.